# Discord.py I cant use dict in python to save user data

Tags: python, dictionary, error-handling, discord.py

I need your help with my code. I am trying to code a leveling system where user can level up with writing. But I cant save users information to dict.

The ".setuplevel" command should write every member from guild except the bot in a dict and give the values [0] = 0 and [1] = 0. [0] is the experience the player has and [1] is the actual level.

Can anyone help me?

Code:

```
users = {}

async def add_experience(self, user, users):
    client.users[f'{user.id}'][0] += 500
    with open('users.yml', 'w') as outfile:
        yaml.dump(client.users, outfile, default_flow_style=False)
    if ((client.users[user.id][1] + 1) * 300) < client.users[user.id][0]:
        print("levelup")

def saveUser(self, user_id):
    print(user_id)
    client.users[f'{user_id}'] = {}
    client.users[f'{user_id}'][0] = 0
    client.users[f'{user_id}'][1] = 0
    with open('users.yml', 'w') as outfile:
        yaml.dump(client.users, outfile, default_flow_style=False)

async def on_ready(self):
    with open("users.yml", 'r') as stream:
        client.users = yaml.safe_load(stream)

async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

            elif message.content == ".setuplevel":
        await message.delete()
        print(message.guild.members)
        for user in message.guild.members:
            if not user == client.user:
                print(user.id)
                client.saveUser(message.author.id)

    elif message.author.id not in client.last_message:
        client.last_message[message.author.id] = message.created_at
    else:
        if (message.created_at - client.last_message[message.author.id]).total_seconds() > 25:
            await client.add_experience(message.author, client.users)
```

And this is the error I get after calling ".setuplevel":

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sanel\PycharmProjects\Log-Host\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/sanel/PycharmProjects/Log-Host/main.py", line 306, in on_message
    if not user == client.user:
  File "C:/Users/sanel/PycharmProjects/Log-Host/main.py", line 79, in saveUser
    client.users[f'{user_id}'] = {}
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the traceback suggests, 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment. Which means value for userid is None and you are trying to use None as a key in the dictionary.

Comment: Actually, it means that `.users` is `None`, not `user_id`. The latter being `None` wouldn't be an error.

Comment: And how can I avoid it? I have set users = {} in the code, where is the mistake?

Comment: @SanelTrnka `yaml.safe_load` must be returning `None`, since that's where you're setting `users`. Double check the docs for the method to see what that means.

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes you´re right! Thanks for your help so much. Lov u :)